# Is it possible to make a posynomial concave using a change of variables?

Tags: convex-optimization, convexity

**Note**: this question was already posted [on Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4770765/652310) but received no answers, so I'm re-posting it here for better reach.

---

Consider the following posynomial with respect to the variables $x_1,\dots,x_n$:
$$
\begin{align}
f(x_1,\dots,x_n) &= \sum_{k=1}^K c_k x_1^{a_{1k}} x_2^{a_{2k}} \cdots x_n^{a_{nk}} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^K c_k \cdot \prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{a_{ik}}
\end{align}
$$
Using the change of variables $\tilde x_i = \log x_i$, such that $x_i = e^{\tilde x_i}$, we get the following expression
$$
\begin{align}
f(\tilde x_1,\dots,\tilde x_n) &= \sum_{k=1}^K c_k \cdot \prod_{i=1}^n e^{\tilde x_i a_{ik}} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^K c_k \cdot \exp\left[\sum_{i=1}^n \tilde x_i a_{ik}\right] \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^K \exp(\log(c_k)) \cdot \exp\left[\sum_{i=1}^n \tilde x_i a_{ik}\right] \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^K \exp\left[\sum_{i=1}^n \tilde x_i a_{ik} + \log(c_k)\right]
\end{align}
$$
This expression is convex with respect to $\tilde x_1,\dots,\tilde x_n$ (see [here](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Eee127/sp21/livebook/def_lse_fcn.html) for a proof). **My question is**: does there exist a similar change of variables such that the resulting expression is *concave* (not convex) with respect to $\tilde x_1,\dots,\tilde x_n$? That is, does there exist functions $g_1,\dots,g_n$ such that $f(\tilde x_1,\dots,\tilde x_n)$, where $\tilde x_i = g_i(x_i)$, is concave with respect to $\tilde x_1,\dots,\tilde x_n$?

Comment: I see you implicitly assume $c_k > 0 \;\forall k$ and $x_i > 0 \;\forall i$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You implicitly assume $c_k > 0$ for all $k$, and $x_i > 0$ for all $i$, and I will do the same. Using the change of variables $\tilde x_i = x_i^M$, such that $x_i = \tilde x_i^{1/M}$, for a big constant $M$ at least the size of the largest monomial degree, $\max_k \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_{ik}\right)$, we get the following expression
$$
\begin{align}
f(\tilde x_1,\dots,\tilde x_n) &= \sum_{k=1}^K c_k \cdot \prod_{i=1}^n {\tilde x_i^{a_{ik}/M}}, \\
\end{align}
$$
which is a sum of monomials of degree $p_k = \sum_i \frac{a_{ik}}{M} \leq 1$ known to be concave and representable by a power cone in conic optimization; see [here](https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/powo.html#the-most-general-power-cone) for homogenous case $p_k=1$, and [here](https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/powo.html#non-homogenous-constraints) for the nonhomogenous case $p_k<1$. The expression above is thus concave with respect to $\tilde x_1,\dots,\tilde x_n$.

Comment: Very clever. Thank you for this answer.

Comment: Just wondering, do you know if there is a similar change of variables such that the function $$h(x,y) = \prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{z_i} \cdot y_i^{1-z_i}$$ where $x,y \in \mathbb R_+^n$ and $h(x,y)$ is a monomial in $(x,y)$, is concave in $(x,y)$? That is, does there exist $\tilde x = g_1(x)$ and $\tilde y = g_2(y)$ such that $h(\tilde x,\tilde y)$ is concave? You can further assume that $z_i \in [0,1]$ and $x_i,y_i \in [0,1]$ if it makes things easier. I can also post this as a separate question if you prefer.

Comment: If $z_i$ are constant isn't this just a special case of the above with K=1 where the monomial degree is (z1 + (1-z1) + z2 + (1-z2) + ...) = n? If in doubt, create a separate question yes.

Comment: Ahh yes! Don't know why I didn't see that. Thanks again.